# How to multiply displayed TextView Integer values on multiple buttons click

Tags: android, android-studio, for-loop, button, textview

i have 10 buttons with 2 columns like 5x2. These 2 columns contains for loops with 5 buttons each with textviews for each column and when user clicks any button of these 2 columns 2 textview integers are displayed. I wanna multiply these displayed numbers to get final result in 3rd Textview but its not multiplying, below is the code I written:

```js
public class MultiplicationActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private static final int[] column1_buttonsArrays = {R.id.column1_button0, R.id.column1_button1, R.id.column1_button2, R.id.column1_button3, R.id.column1_button4};
    private Button[] c1_buttons = new Button[column1_buttonsArrays.length];
    int i1;
    private static final int[] column2_buttonsArrays = {R.id.column2_button0, R.id.column2_button1, R.id.column2_button2, R.id.column2_button3, R.id.column2_button4};
    private Button[] c2_buttons = new Button[column2_buttonsArrays.length];
    int i2;
    int num1, num2, solution1;
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.multiplication);
        
           dummyTextValue1 = findViewById(R.id.dummy_value1);
           dummyTextValue2 = findViewById(R.id.dummy_value2);
           multipliedText = findViewById(R.id.multiplied_value);
        
           for(i1 = 0; i1 < column1_buttonsArrays.length; i1++) {
           c1_buttons[i1] = findViewById(column1_buttonsArrays[i1_buttons]);
           c1_buttons[i1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
             switch (view.getId()) {
             case R.id.column1_button0:
                 dummyTextValue1.setText("0");
                 break;
             case R.id.column1_button1:
                 dummyTextValue1.setText("1");
                 break;
             case R.id.column1_button2:
                 dummyTextValue1.setText("2");
                 break;
             case R.id.column1_button3:
                 dummyTextValue1.setText("3");
                 break;
             case R.id.column1_button4:
                 dummyTextValue1.setText("4");
                 break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
            for(i2 = 0; i2 < column2_buttonsArrays.length; i2++) {
            c2_buttons[i2] = findViewById(column2_buttonsArrays[i2_buttons]);
            c2_buttons[i2].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
              switch (view.getId()) {
             case R.id.column2_button0:
                 dummyTextValue2.setText("0");
                 break;
             case R.id.column2_button1:
                 dummyTextValue2.setText("1");
                 break;
             case R.id.column2_button2:
                 dummyTextValue2.setText("2");
                 break;
             case R.id.column2_button3:
                 dummyTextValue2.setText("3");
                 break;
             case R.id.column2_button4:
                 dummyTextValue2.setText("4");
                 break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    String value1 = dummyTextValue1.getText().toString();
    String value2 = dummyTextValue2.getText().toString();
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
    solution1 = (int) (num1 * num2);
    multipliedText.setText(solution1);
  }
}
```

Not understanding where I'm doing wrong. Please give me an idea or updated code that how can I get multiplied displayed values from for loop. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `solution` variable is an integer.
`solution1 = (int) (num1 * num2);`

In android, `TextView.setText(int resource)` can be used to set a String resources in the TextView. You will want to use `TextView.setText(String text)`. Check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(int))

You can do that like this:

```
multipliedText.setText(String.valueOf(solution1));
```

The other problem is that `multipliedText.setText()` is executed as soon as the Activity is created. E.g. both dummyValues will be empty. You need execute this line, after the buttons are clicked.

Something like this:

```
dummyTextValue1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
             //..
        }

        String value1 = dummyTextValue1.getText().toString();
        String value2 = dummyTextValue2.getText().toString();
        updateText(value1, value2);
   }
});

private void updateText(String value1, String value2, TextView textView) {

    num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
    solution1 = (int) (num1 * num2);
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(solution1));
}
```

This will call updateText everytime one of the buttons is clicked, and hence, update your text. Good luck

Comment: I have edited MultipliedText to String, even the value is not changing. Any other solution please..?

Comment: No luck to me. Multiplied Text not updating.

Comment: How can I place code for 2nd Switch, You have given for 1st Switch and multiplied value showing only for 1st column buttons click.

Comment: Hi @Entreco Thank you for your support. I have placed String values and updatedText in all switch cases and now code is working perfectly as I wanted. Once again Thank you and you saved my day...+100